# Yii2 GridView hide column conditionally

Tags: gridview, yii, yii2

I am displaying some columns in Yii2 GridView widget, 'Executive Name' is one of those but it should be displayed only when a Supervisor is logged in not when Executive logged in.

When I am hard coding visible to zero it is not displaying as follows:

```
[
    'label' => 'Executive Name',
    'attribute' => 'cs.first_name',
    'visible' => '0',
],
```

But I want to display it conditionally something like this:

```
[
    'label' => 'Executive Name',
    'attribute' => 'cs.first_name',
    'visible' => function ($data) {
        if ($data->hc_customersupport->is_supervisor) {
            return '1'; // or return true;
        } else {
            return '0'; // or return false;
        }
    },
],
```

Please tell if this approach is correct.

Comment: checkboxOptions property is very helpful to achieve this

Answer (score 18):

`yii\grid\DataColumn` is extended from `yii\grid\Column` which has [visible](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-column.html#$visible-detail) property. As you can see from the docs, it only accepts boolean values, but of course you can dynamically calculate those by passing an expression returning boolean value. Example with RBAC:

```
use Yii;

...

'visible' => Yii::$app->user->can('supervisor'),
```

Passing callable is not allowed and doesn't make any sense. Logically think about this - why visibility of the whole column is dependent from concrete row (model)?

**P.S.** You should return boolean, not integer or string. Also your expression can be reduced to just this:

```
return $data->hc_customersupport->is_supervisor;
```

But `is_supervisor` check is definetely wrong, it should be not called like that (through model). It's better to use RBAC instead.

Answer (score 10):

This one works fine

```
[
    'label' => 'Executive Name',
    'attribute' => 'cs.first_name',
    'visible' => 'Condition' ? true : false
],
```

You can replace the text `'Condition'` with your condition let  say `Yii::$app->user->can('supervisor')` if this parameter works fine for you.

Answer (score 2):

For me it's working, make one more action with $rowvisible=1 and same view render:
Model

```
class SomeClass extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    public $rowvisible;
...
```

Controller

```
public function actionIndex()
    {
        $rowvisible = 0;
        $searchModel = new PostSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(Yii::$app->request->queryParams);

        return $this->render('index', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
            'rowvisible'=>$rowvisible,
        ]);
    }
```

View

```
[ 'attribute'=>'SomeAttribute',
  'visible' => ($rowvisible==1) ,
  'header' => 'Some Header',  
  'contentOptions' => ['style' => 'width: 4%; background-color:#f3d8d8;'],
  'headerOptions' => ['style'=>'font-weight: normal; font-size: 8pt;'],  
  'value'=>    function ($model) {some arithmetic}
],
```

Answer (score 0):

visible is boolean, you dont need use function.
you can add condition like this

```
'visible'=> ($data=="supervisor"),
```

if true will be hidden , if false will be visible.
vice versa

```
'visible'=> ($data!="supervisor"),
```

Answer (score -2):

You can do by giving condition in your Model Search's query.
In your search function

```
public function search($params)
 {
  query = Table::find()->where(['Column' => 'condition' ] );
  /* Remaining code */
 }
```