# Show/Hide Grid View Action Column Based On Condition - Yii2

Tags: php, gridview, yii2, yii2-basic-app, yii2-widget

I was trying to *show/hide ActionColumn* based on some condition. 
In my system, 2 roles are defined : `Primary` & `Secondary`. I wanted to hide **ActionColumn** for `Role Secondary` and to show **ActionColumn** for `Role Primary`.

I got one `visible` attribute option from [$visible](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-column.html#$visible-detail). Where, `'visible'=> true` and `'visible'=> false` are working properly.

```
<?
[
  'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
  'visible' => false,
    .
    .
    .
]
```

But, **Problem is**: I wanted to set `visible` option as `True` / `False` dynamically based on some condition.

```
<?
[
  'class' => 'yii\grid\ActionColumn',
  'visible' => function ($data) {
      if (Yii::$app->userinfo->hasRole([AR::ROLE_PRIMARY])) {
        return true;
      } 
      if (Yii::$app->userinfo->hasRole([AR::ROLE_SECONDARY])) {
        return false;
      }
  },
    .
    .
    .
]
```

I tried in this way too. But, didn't got luck. Any help/hint/suggestion is appreciable.

I searched [Yii2 GridView hide column conditionally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32196111/yii2-gridview-hide-column-conditionally).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't set visible to a callable, although there is nothing to stop you setting a variable before calling the gridview.

In this case though, visibility is only dependant on whether they have the primary role, you can just use:

```
'visible' => Yii::$app->userinfo->hasRole([AR::ROLE_PRIMARY])
```

Comment: Well Done. (Y). It worked. But, Why It was not working on such condition. As, it was not having any error and logically returning true/false value.

Comment: @Nana Partykar : bro need your advice. Ask Question facility ban ho gai he. Mene doc read kiya or sare question  ko properly edit kiya.. but fir bhi ban hta nai he. Pls help...

Comment: I'm first time seeing this problem. So, I don't have much idea into it. May be **moderator** did this. May be Some problem from your side only. Ask/Contact Stack overflow Support Biraadar @vijaynathji

Answer (score 2):

**You can use conditional statement to hide particular checkbox in grid view**

```
 Here is simple code which works for me

       [
         'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn', 
         'checkboxOptions' => function($dataProvider) {
                              return ["value" => ($dataProvider['tiIsPaid'] == 0)?$dataProvider['iDriverEarningId']:'',"style"=>($dataProvider['tiIsPaid'] == 0)?'':'display:none'];},
       ]
```

Here i have used simple logic to hide checkbox for particular column

- Set value null or blank so it can not be selected when you click on select all  checkbox
- Hide check box using display none property of css

Hope this help you in hiding particular column based on your conditions.